# Opening do-files in one Stata instance through Nautilus

Tags: stata

I'm using Stata on Ubuntu and managed to link do-files to the `xstata` command. Now when I click onto a .do from my file manager, Stata and the file in the do-file editor are opened.
When I want to open another .do file by clicking on it another instance of Stata is opened for this do file.

Is there a way to force Stata to open all .do files in one instance of Stata?

Comment: Short answer: I doubt it. Bit longer: Why not just open Stata and then your do files? You could write a do-file to open them all up in a series of `doedit` calls if you want several such windows open at once.  But why do you want to do this any way?  If in a project do-files call each other, you just need a master do file to do that.

Comment: Suppose I have a folder full of do files open in my file manager, and I want to take a look at some of them, this would be convenient.

Comment: I agree this would be great if it existed as a preference in the settings. If I want to open many do-files in the same do-file editor (although, I almost always use a dedicated code editor) then I open a do-file editor and drag the files to the open do-file editor window.